# Align the camera to make screen space origin at the bottom-left corner

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm reading the book ["Learn Unity for 2D game development"](http://www.apress.com/9781430262299), and I don't know how to do this:

*"The camera has been aligned in the world so that the screen space origin is at the bottom-left corner; meaning positive X spans across the screen width, and positive Y across the screen height from bottom to top."*

I'm new on Unity and the book doesn't talk how to do it.

By the way, I'm using Unity 4.3.3f1 on a Windows 7.

**How can I align the camera to make screen space origin at the bottom-left corner?**

Comment: Unless I'm misreading this you don't really *do* anything.  All it's saying is that if you reference camera pixel (0,0) that's bottom left (no matter how the camera is oriented/positioned).  I dislike the author's wording, unless of course I've misunderstand him/her.  :)

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing screen space with world space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a 2D game, you have an X-axis and Y-axis. When increasing an object's X-value, you could say the object is going right. When increasing the Y-value, you could say the object is going up.

In a 3D game, there is another additional axis, the Z-axis. This makes it possible to gain 'depth' in games.

Example:

[image: X, Y and Z axis]

If you wanna create a 2D game in a 3D environment, you'll have to 'remove' one of the axis. The most common is to remove the Z-axis to keep the naming in line (X and Y remain, like in a 2D game).

To achieve 'removing' an axis in a 3D environment, your view has to be looking straight at it. In this case, X and Y rotation can be anything but your Z rotation has to be 0.

Example:

[image: X and Y axis]

Consider the above picture to have a Z-axis as well. But because you are looking from Z=0 towards the origin, the line doesn't go to the right, left up or bottom. The axis will be like 1 pixel size.

When you do this using the camera, in such a way that the `world` origin is in front of you and higher X numbers are to your right and higher Y numbers are above you, you've achieved this. This also means that the `screen`'s value of X=0 is totally left, and the `screen`'s value of Y=0 is totally bottom. This concludes that space origin is at the bottom-left corner; meaning positive X spans across the screen width, and positive Y across the screen height from bottom to top.

Answer (score 0):

By saying "camera has been aligned", he doesn't mean that you manually align it in the scene, he's saying how screen space origin is at the bottom-left corner by default.

Source: Unity Script Reference